# Finding contiguous geographical units

Tags: leaflet, geojson, d3

On a map with territorial units, I wish to be able to compare a property of one territorial unit with those surrounding it.
How can I find the contiguous territorial units of a specific one ?

Comment: With some javascript programming? Or in a GIS?

Comment: It has to be dynamic on client side, so best would be in javascript programming (I'm using LeafLet combined with D3).

Comment: How dynamic? Could you precompute the adjacency table in a GIS and read that into your client as a JSON file? Or does the front-end not know what the shapes are going to be? One option might be the "turf" JS library for geospatial operations in Javascript...

Comment: Indeed, pre-computing would be the best solution in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best for user experience would probably be to pre-determine in development phase the graph of contiguous areas, so that it is a small file that can be parsed in production on client side without requiring a lot of computations.

Even during development, you could very well use JS to find adjacent areas, but it might be quite cumbersome. If your areas have perfect edging one each other, the adjacent ones will share a few boundary points. You would probably have no choice but iterating over each and every point of every area to find matches. At least you could pre-filter by checking whether each pair of areas have intersecting rectangle bounds.

Unless you can make further assumptions, like minimum size of each area and no gaps, so that if an area A is within the expanded area of B, you could say it is contiguous.

I guess you are working on French cities, so you might be interested in this: https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1127 which links to this file: http://osm13.openstreetmap.fr/~cquest/openfla/export/communes-adjacentes-20140306.txt

Comment: +1 for guessing it's about French cities, though it's French township federations :)
I'll try to find a way of joining the adjacent cities from the file you linked.